# Is it possible to format the result of Ctrl-g in vim?

Tags: vim

Is it possible to change what goes into `<c-g>`’s output? Specifically, I want to add the current `filetype` to to the output.

Comment: I don't think so but why don't you put this info in your statusline?

Comment: @romainl I'm not using `statusline` currently, feels redundant to me for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by overloading the command with a mapping. Since `:file` is the same as `<C-g>`, let's use that; it saves us the `:normal`:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <C-g> :file<Bar>echon ' ' &filetype<CR>
```